# Bookmarklet to activate reader mode in Firefox on Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, bookmarklet

Recently a change happened with Firefox on Android which stopped me from using the work around of adding something to my reading list and opening it from there to force a page into reader mode. With that in mind I tried to find and then finally make a bookmarklet to force a page into reader mode for me.

So far I have found that by adding 'about:reader?url=' to the beginning of a url will try to open any page into reader mode. From there not knowing much about javascript I tried to cludge together something using other examples I found on the web. To start I just figured out how to add to the url and was able to get that working

```
javascript: window.location = window.location + 'about:reader?url=';
```

The above will add onto the end just fine but when I move it to the beginning it no longer works so when I try

```
javascript: window.location = 'about:reader?url=' + window.location;
```

Nothing happens at all even on a page that will just allow reader mode. When I replace the stuff I am adding with just 'test' though it will happily cause the page to go to 'testhttp://www.google.com/' or wherever else. I have tried it on not only my android phone but also my desktop. What am I doing wrong as from what I can see this should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly Firefox considers it to be a security risk to allow Javascript to change a page to any location beginning with `about:`.

Using the Javascript console in Firefox in Windows to run this code:

```
window.location = 'about:reader?url=' + window.location;
```

returns error:

```
Access to 'about:reader?url=...' from script denied
```

Here is a "work around" that might ease your particular pain:

```
javascript:(function(){prompt('Copy the below text and then paste it into the URL bar:', 'about:reader?url='+encodeURIComponent(document.location))})();
```

It will prompt you with a url you can copy and then paste into the URL bar.

Comment: Well that puts me in a pickle if there isn't a way around it.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunate. BTW, since you seem new to Stack Overflow, please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: I was half hoping someone would come flying in and mention a work around or something.

Comment: Thats actually quite a decent work around, thank you