# How to avoid about:blank#blocked with window.location?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a page which redirects to a reader mode(about:reader?url=X) version of a page in Firefox yet when I try it it gets blocked ( `Uncaught TypeError: Location.href setter: Access to 'about:reader?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com' from script denied.` in the console ), I tried chromium based browsers just to check and it redirects me to about:blank#blocked, any ideas?

My current code is `window.location = "about:reader?url=" + url` and I could not find a solution about it online. I could try setting an `<a>` link to the page I want to go but I don't really wanna do that, I'll do it if there isn't any solutions

Comment: Unfortunately, due to security issues, it looks like this isn't allowed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752527/bookmarklet-to-activate-reader-mode-in-firefox-on-android

Comment: ouch, welp thanks anyways